# How to say 'moved to [place]' or 'enrolled at [place]

Tags: translation, grammar, vocabulary

I want to either say last year I moved to Leeds or last year I started studying at Leeds University.

Comment: Please remember to include translation attempt, close vote pending edit: Questions  are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated

Comment: `moved to xxx: 搬家到 xxx` `enrolled at xxx: 进入xxx学习`

Answer (score 2):

去年 (last year) 我 (I) 搬 (moved) 到 (to) ... (name of place)。

Qùnián wǒ bān dào ...

去年 (last year) 我 (I) 开始 (started) 在 (at) ... (name of university) 读书 (study)。

Qùnián wǒ kāishǐ zài ... dúshū

去年 (last year) 我 (I) 被 (by) ....(name of university) 录取 (enrolled) 了。

Qùnián wǒ bèi ... lùqǔle.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's question, it should be

我去年搬到了利兹大学.

我去年开始在利兹大学念书.

Comment: is it *that* hard to look up Leeds University? 利兹大学

Comment: @user3306356 Thanks for your comment, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
last year I moved to Leeds.
去年我搬到了利兹居住。

last year I started studying at Leeds University.
我从去年开始进入利兹大学念书。

'moved to [place]'
搬 到 [place]

'enrolled at [place]
进入/参加/录取 到 [place], 录取：get admitted to the University.
```